# Stuck at splash screen when changing to GDM

Tags: boot, gnome, lightdm, plymouth, gdm

After considering it for a while, I finally decided to install GNOME onto my Ubuntu 14.04 system to give it a play and see if I it was worth switching to Ubuntu GNOME. Everything seems to be fine (after a little fiddling) and very user-friendly, but I'm not very pleased with the lockscreen ([this](https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-bIDrTKTRPdk/TyE9PinpxeI/AAAAAAAACnc/eWuq2S6UdIg/s800/Screenshot%252520-%25252001262012%252520-%25252012%25253A46%25253A13%252520PM.png) kind of thing).

After looking around, I found that the way to change it to GNOME's new lockscreen is by changing from LightDM to GDM. When I do this, however, the system gets stuck at the purple "Ubuntu with dots underneath it" splash screen. I can boot normally by changing back to LightDM, but that doesn't solve the initial problem.

Does anyone have any ideas why I can't get into GDM? Or is there a different way to achieve my aim that I'm missing?

Thanks!

Comment: If you wait long enough at the purple dots screen, the TTYs should have started up, and you can switch to one of those using Ctrl-Alt-F2. From there, if you do `sudo service restart gdm`, does anything happen? COuld you also post the X and GDM logs?